# Wire assignment inside IF block

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I'm having trouble assigning a value to a wire inside an `if` block. I would have thought this would be fairly straight forward, but the error I'm getting is:

```
near "assign": syntax error, unexpected assign, expecting IDENTIFIER or TYPE_IDENTIFIER or NETTYPE_IDENTIFIER.
```

This is my module code:

```
module fulladder(input logic S, a, b, cin,
                 output logic s, cout);
  
  wire b_;
  
  assign b_ = b;
  always_comb
  begin
    if (S) begin:
      assign b_ = ~b;
    end
  end

  wire p, g;
  assign p = a ^ b;
  assign g = a & b;
  assign s = p ^ cin;
  assign cout = g | (p & cin);
endmodule
```

I'm trying to invert `b` if `S`=1 (convert A + B into A - B using 2's-complement).

Is this approach workable? Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You can model this behavior with a mux, and a common way to do that is to use the conditional operator:

```
module fulladder(input logic S, a, b, cin,
                 output logic s, cout);
  
  wire b_ = (S) ? ~b : b;
  
  wire p, g;
  assign p = a ^ b;
  assign g = a & b;
  assign s = p ^ cin;
  assign cout = g | (p & cin);
endmodule
```

This fixes all compile errors.

---

The specific error message you get is due to the colon after the begin keyword (`begin:`).  When you use a colon there, it must be followed by a block name identifier, but it is followed by another keyword (`assign`) which is on the next line.  You either meant to give the block a unique name (which is optional), or the colon is a typo.

Even if the colon is removed, you should not use an `assign` keyword inside any type of `always` block.  Also, you should not make assignments to a signal with both a continuous assignment (your 1st `assign` statement) and from within an `always` block.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to use the same way of writing (assignment, then override if condition S is found), I would do it like this:

```
    logic b_;
    always_comb begin
        b_ = b;
        if (S) begin
            b_ = ~b;
        end
    end
```

I opted for this solution since it is similar to the original code, and in the title it was explicitly asked to include assignment inside an *IF block*, even though probably the ternary operator shown by *@toolic* is the cleaner solution.

Please also notice that in the following part of your code `b_` is not used anywhere yet, so our solutions are pointless so far.